# Rally custom app : How to Filter the standard defect trend report for a Story

Tags: sdk, rally

We have a single story  per release "Automation tests" We log all our defect originated from automation test under this story. . Now would like to create a custom report around defect generated for automation story .
 Example would a defect trend app that pulls defect only from that story .  .
Can standard reports be customized at the story level ?
General flow of my report will be .

1. Select the Release (behind the scene, app automatically looks into the automation test story for all the defects )
   Or  Select the story from the drop-down<>
   2.Display the report

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve above problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to leverage AppSDK2 and Lookback API (LBAPI). Use AppSDK2 to grab the Story or Stories of interest into a WsapiDataStore. Then reach into LBAPI for those stories to grab the Defect history for each story in a SnapshotStore - which you can then use to categorize and chart. I'll see if I can work/scare up an example - this is an ideal use case for the new Rally APIs.

Comment: Thanks  , I would greatly appreciate an example.